# No sound via "built-in audio" after using HDMI sound -Solved-

Tags: sound

Recently I ran

```
speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3
```

to get sound from my laptop via HDMI to my TV, however now I can't revert to the "built-in audio" (headphones & laptop speakers). 
How do I modify this command to (or otherwise) fix this issue?

It automagicly fixed itself when I reconnected the hdmi connector and then pulled the plug out again.